# Cordova can't add Android platform unknown command 'ant'

Tags: android, cordova, ant, command-prompt

I'm trying to successfully install and create an app with cordova but it doesn't works.
So I've Googled and read many threads here on Stack Overflow but it hasn't helped.

Here's my problem:
If I try to add the Android platform via CMD with

```
cordova platform add android
```

I get the folowing error:

```
Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added
to your path.
at C:\Users\user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

I've downloaded Apache ant and unzipped it into `C:\ant`.
My env vars are the following:

Path:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\dev\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-
tools;C:\dev\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools;C:\Program     
Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40;C:\ant
```

(I tried `c:\ant\bin` and `c:\ant`)
JAVA_HOME:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40
```

ANT_HOME:

```
C:\ant
```

And it still isn't working. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `....;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME\bin` in your path?

Comment: let me know so I can assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

Install ant using brew

Download and install Homebrew by executing following command in terminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Install Apache Ant via Homebrew by executing

```
brew install ant
```

Run the PhoneGap build again and it should successfully compile and install your Android app.

Answer (score -1):

add C:\ant\bin; in your system path.

Then open cmd prompt. type ant -version if show like this. you will fix it.

`ant -version`

`Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013`

if it's didn't resolve your problem then check your ant install path. May be C:\Program Files\ant\bin .then add it to your system path.
enjoy your code.